# On $\int_0^\infty \sin^bt\ e^{-st}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

While mucking about with powers of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, I found something cool which might help me solve the following integral
$$F(b,s)=\int_0^\infty \sin^b(t)e^{-st}dt$$
Integration by parts with $dv=e^{-st}dt$ gives
$$F(b,s)=\frac{b}s\int_0^\infty\sin^{b-1}t\cos t\ e^{-st}dt$$
Integration by parts again with $dv=e^{-st}dt$ gives
$$F(b,s)=\frac{b(1-b)}{s^2}\int_0^\infty\sin^{b-2}t\cos^2t\ e^{-st}dt+\frac{b}{s^2}\int_0^\infty\sin^bte^{-st}dt$$
$$F(b,s)=\frac{b(1-b)}{s^2}\int_0^\infty\sin^{b-2}t(1-\sin^2t)e^{-st}dt+\frac{b}{s^2}F(b,s)$$
$$F(b,s)=\frac{b(1-b)}{s^2}F(b-2,s)+\frac{b^2}{s^2}F(b,s)$$
$$\bigg(1-\frac{b^2}{s^2}\bigg)F(b,s)=\frac{b(1-b)}{s^2}F(b-2,s)$$
$$F(b,s)=\frac{b(1-b)}{s^2-b^2}F(b-2,s)$$
My question: how can we evaluate $F(b,s)$?

**Update:**

I've found that, for non-integer $b$, 
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\sin^bt\ dt=\prod_{n\geq0}\frac{(b-2n)(1-b+2n)}{s^2-(b-2n)^2}$$
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\cos^bt\ dt=\prod_{n\geq0}\frac{(b-2n)(b-2n-1)}{s^2+(b-2n)^2}$$
I'm still working on the case in which $b$ is an integer, though.

Comment: Well, $F(1,s)=\frac{1}{s^2+1}$: http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/LaplaceZTable/LaplaceZFuncTable.html , so you now can find $F(b,s)$ for all odd positive integer $b$.

Comment: @AndyWalls how do we use $F(1,s)$ to find $F(b,s)$ for odd natural $b$?

Comment: You can find $F(3, s)$ using $F(1, s)$.  You can find $F(5, s)$ using $F(3, s)$, etc.

Comment: @andywalls right... can we use it to find the even values?

Comment: Find the convolution of $F(1, s)$ with itself to find $F(2, s)$, I think.  Or use the integral directly to find $F(2, s)$ using a trig identity to reduce $\sin^2()$ to something simpler.

Comment: $F(0,s)=1/s$, this allows to find $F(2n,s)$

Comment: By the way, the recurrence relation has a singularity at $b=s$, but the integral exists in this case (for natural values of $s$). It seems like there is a mistake in the calculation.

Comment: $\mathcal{L}_t\left[\sin ^b(a t)\right](s)=\frac{\left(b! a^b\right) \prod _{k=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{b}{2}\right\rfloor } \frac{1}{s^2+4 \left(k+\frac{1}{4}
   \left(1-(-1)^b\right)\right)^2 a^2}}{s^{\frac{2}{4} \left(1-(-1)^b\right)-1}}$ from book: https://www.amazon.com/Integrals-Direct-Laplace-Transforms/dp/2881248373

Comment: @atarasenko what's the error?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk See my recent edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F(b,s)$ can be calculated for integer values of $b$ using recursion:
$$F(b,s)=\frac{b}{s}\int_0^\infty \sin^{b-1}t \cos{t}e^{-st}\,dt=-\frac{b}{s^2}\int_0^\infty \sin^{b-1}t \cos{t}\,d(e^{-st})$$
$$=\frac{b}{s^2}\int_0^\infty ((b-1)\sin^{b-2}t \cos^2{t}-\sin^b{t})e^{-st}\, dt$$
$$=\frac{b}{s^2}\int_0^\infty ((b-1)\sin^{b-2}t-b\sin^b{t})e^{-st}\, dt=\frac{b(b-1)}{s^2}F(b-2,s)-\frac{b^2}{s^2}F(b,s),$$
which leads to:
$$F(b,s)=\frac{b(b-1)}{b^2+s^2}F(b-2,s)$$
Also, $F(0,s)=1/s$ (integral of the exponential), and $F(1,s)=1/(1+s^2)$ (can be obtained by representing $\sin{x}$ as a sum of exponentials).
Therefore:
$$F(b,s)=b!s\,\Pi_{k=0}^{\lfloor b/2\rfloor}\frac{1}{s^2+(2k)^2}, \quad b=2n$$
$$F(b,s)=b!\,\Pi_{k=0}^{\lfloor b/2\rfloor}\frac{1}{s^2+(2k+1)^2}, \quad b=2n-1$$

Comment: Beautiful! One question: does the $d(e^{-st})$ mean integration by parts with $dv=e^{-st}dt$? I am unfamiliar with this notation.

Comment: $d$ is the differential of a function: if $v=e^{-st}$, then $dv=d(e^{-st})=-se^{-st}\,dt$

Comment: Oh now I see. Thanks!